# Problem in Flink UI on Mesos cluster with two slave nodes

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, apache-zookeeper, mesos, marathon

I have four physical nodes with docker installed on each of them. I configured Mesos,Flink,Zookeeper,Hadoop and Marathon on docker of each one. I had already had three nodes,one slave and two masters, that I had run Flink on Marathon and its UI had been run without any problems. After that, I changed the cluster,two masters and two slaves. I added this Json file in Marathon, it was ran, but Flink UI was not shown in both slave nodes. The error is in following.

```
 {
 "id": "flink",
 "cmd": "/home/flink-1.7.2/bin/mesos-appmaster.sh -Djobmanager.heap.mb=1024 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=6123 -Drest.port=8081 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=1024 -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=2 -Dparallelism.default=2 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1",
"cpus": 1.0,
"mem": 1024,
"instances": 2
}
```

Error:

> Service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. Please refresh

I cleared Zookeeper contents with this commands:

```
  /home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/zkCleanup.sh /var/lib/zookeeper/data/ -n 10
  rm -rf /var/lib/zookeeper/data/version-2
  rm /var/lib/zookeeper/data/zookeeper_server.pid
```

Also, I ran this command and delete Flink contents in Zookeeper:

```
  /home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/zkCli.sh
  delete /flink/default/leader/....
```

But still one of Flink UI has problem.

I have configured Flink high availability like this:

```
  high-availability: zookeeper
  high-availability.storageDir: hdfs:///flink/ha/
  high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: 0.0.0.0:2181,10.32.0.3:2181,10.32.0.4:2181,10.32.0.5:2181
  fs.hdfs.hadoopconf: /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop
  fs.hdfs.hdfssite: /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml
  recovery.zookeeper.path.mesos-workers: /mesos-workers
  env.java.home: /opt/java
  mesos.master: 10.32.0.2:5050,10.32.0.3:5050
```

Because I used Mesos cluster, I did not change any thing in **flink-conf.yaml**.

This is part of slave log which has error:

```
 - Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: 
   Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:37797
   2019-07-03 07:22:42,922 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        
- Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@localhost:37797] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. 
Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@localhost:37797]] 
Caused by: [Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:37797]
2019-07-03 07:22:43,003 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                    
- Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: 
 Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:37797
 2019-07-03 07:22:43,004 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        
 - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@localhost:37797] 
 has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. 
 Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@localhost:37797]] 
  Caused by: [Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:37797]
  2019-07-03 07:22:43,072 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                    
 - Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: 
   Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:37797
   2019-07-03 07:22:43,073 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        
  - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@localhost:37797] 
  has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. 
  Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@localhost:37797]] 
  Caused by: [Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:37797]
   2019-07-03 07:23:45,891 WARN  
org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.retriever.impl.RpcGatewayRetriever  

- Error while retrieving the leader gateway. Retrying to connect to 
akka.tcp://flink@localhost:37797/user/dispatcher.
```

This is Zookeeper log for the node that has the error in Flink UI:

```
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,425 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@136] - Reading configuration from: /home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,434 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer$QuorumServer@185] - Resolved hostname: 0.0.0.0 to address: /0.0.0.0
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,435 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer$QuorumServer@185] - Resolved hostname: 10.32.0.3 to address: /10.32.0.3
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,435 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer$QuorumServer@185] - Resolved hostname: 10.32.0.2 to address: /10.32.0.2
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,435 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer$QuorumServer@185] - Resolved hostname: 10.32.0.5 to address: /10.32.0.5
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,435 [myid:] - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@354] - Non-optimial configuration, consider an odd number of servers.
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,436 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@398] - Defaulting to majority quorums
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,438 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,438 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,438 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,445 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerMain@130] - Starting quorum peer
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,450 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:ServerCnxnFactory@117] - Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,452 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@89] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,458 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer@1159] - tickTime set to 2000
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,458 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer@1205] - initLimit set to 10
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,458 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer@1179] - minSessionTimeout set to -1
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,459 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer@1190] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,464 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer@1470] - QuorumPeer communication is not secured!
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,464 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer@1499] - quorum.cnxn.threads.size set to 20
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,465 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer@669] - currentEpoch not found! Creating with a reasonable default of 0. This should only happen when you are upgrading your installation
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,519 [myid:3] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeer@684] - acceptedEpoch not found! Creating with a reasonable default of 0. This should only happen when you are upgrading your installation
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,566 [myid:3] - INFO  [ListenerThread:QuorumCnxManager$Listener@736] - My election bind port: /0.0.0.0:3888
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,574 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:QuorumPeer@910] - LOOKING
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,575 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:FastLeaderElection@813] - New election. My id =  3, proposed zxid=0x0
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,581 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection@595] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x200000004 (n.zxid), 0x5 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 1 (n.sid), 0x2 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state)
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,581 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection@595] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x200000004 (n.zxid), 0x5 (n.round), LEADING (n.state), 1 (n.sid), 0x3 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state)
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,581 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection@595] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 3 (n.leader), 0x0 (n.zxid), 0x1 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 3 (n.sid), 0x0 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state)
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,582 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerSender[myid=3]:QuorumCnxManager@347] - Have smaller server identifier, so dropping the connection: (4, 3)
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,583 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection@595] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x200000004 (n.zxid), 0x5 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 3 (n.sid), 0x2 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state)
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,583 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerSender[myid=3]:QuorumCnxManager@347] - Have smaller server identifier, so dropping the connection: (4, 3)
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,583 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection@595] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x200000004 (n.zxid), 0x5 (n.round), LEADING (n.state), 1 (n.sid), 0x3 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state)
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,584 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection@595] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x200000004 (n.zxid), 0x5 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0x2 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state)
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,585 [myid:3] - INFO  [/0.0.0.0:3888:QuorumCnxManager$Listener@743] - Received connection request /10.32.0.5:42182
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,585 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection@595] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x200000004 (n.zxid), 0x5 (n.round), FOLLOWING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0x3 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state)
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,585 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection@595] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x200000004 (n.zxid), 0x5 (n.round), FOLLOWING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0x3 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state)
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,587 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection@595] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x200000004 (n.zxid), 0x5 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 4 (n.sid), 0x2 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state)
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,587 [myid:3] - WARN  [RecvWorker:4:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@1025] - Connection broken for id 4, my id = 3, error = 
   java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:1010)
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,589 [myid:3] - WARN  [RecvWorker:4:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@1028] - Interrupting SendWorker
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,588 [myid:3] - INFO  [/0.0.0.0:3888:QuorumCnxManager$Listener@743] - Received connection request /10.32.0.5:42184
 2019-07-03 09:43:33,589 [myid:3] - WARN  [SendWorker:4:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@941] - Interrupted while waiting for message on queue
 java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2088)
at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:418)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.pollSendQueue(QuorumCnxManager.java:1094)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.access$700(QuorumCnxManager.java:74)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:929)
   2019-07-03 09:43:33,589 [myid:3] - WARN  [SendWorker:4:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@951] - Send worker leaving thread
   2019-07-03 09:43:33,590 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection@595] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x200000004 (n.zxid), 0x5 (n.round), FOLLOWING (n.state), 4 (n.sid), 0x3 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state)
   2019-07-03 09:43:33,590 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:QuorumPeer@980] - FOLLOWING
   2019-07-03 09:43:33,591 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection@595] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x200000004 (n.zxid), 0x5 (n.round), FOLLOWING (n.state), 4 (n.sid), 0x3 (n.peerEpoch) FOLLOWING (my state)
   2019-07-03 09:43:33,593 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Learner@86] - TCP NoDelay set to: true
   2019-07-03 09:43:33,597 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.14-4c25d480e66aadd371de8bd2fd8da255ac140bcf, built on 03/06/2019 16:18 GMT
   2019-07-03 09:43:33,597 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:host.name=629a802d822d
   2019-07-03 09:43:33,597 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.version=1.8.0_191
   2019-07-03 09:43:33,597 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
   2019-07-03 09:43:33,597 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
   2019-07-03 09:43:33,598 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.class.path=/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../zookeeper-server/target/classes:/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../build/classes:/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../zookeeper-server/target/lib/*.jar:/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../lib/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.14.jar:/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../zookeeper-server/src/main/resources/lib/*.jar:/home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/../conf:
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,598 [myid:3] - INFO  
  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,598 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,598 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,598 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.name=Linux
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,598 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.arch=amd64
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,598 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.version=4.18.0-21-generic
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,598 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.name=root
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,598 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.home=/root
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,598 [myid:3] - INFO   [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.dir=/
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,599 [myid:3] - INFO  
    [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@174] - Created server with tickTime 2000 minSessionTimeout 4000 maxSessionTimeout 40000 datadir /var/lib/zookeeper/data/version-2 snapdir /var/lib/zookeeper/data/version-2
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,600 [myid:3] - INFO  
  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Follower@65] - FOLLOWING - LEADER ELECTION TOOK - 25
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,601 [myid:3] - INFO  
     [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:QuorumPeer$QuorumServer@185] - Resolved hostname: 10.32.0.2 to address: /10.32.0.2
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,637 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Learner@336] - Getting a snapshot from leader 0x300000000
  2019-07-03 09:43:33,644 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:FileTxnSnapLog@301] - Snapshotting: 0x300000000 to /var/lib/zookeeper/data/version-2/snapshot.300000000
  2019-07-03 09:44:24,320 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@222] - Accepted socket connection from /150.20.11.157:55744
  2019-07-03 09:44:24,324 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@949] - Client attempting to establish new session at /150.20.11.157:55744
  2019-07-03 09:44:24,327 [myid:3] - WARN  
   [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2181:Follower@119] - Got zxid 0x300000001 expected 0x1
  2019-07-03 09:44:24,327 [myid:3] - INFO  [SyncThread:3:FileTxnLog@216] - Creating new log file: log.300000001
  2019-07-03 09:44:24,384 [myid:3] - INFO  [CommitProcessor:3:ZooKeeperServer@694] - Established session 0x300393be5860000 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /150.20.11.157:55744
  2019-07-03 09:44:24,892 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@222] - Accepted socket connection from /150.20.11.157:55746
  2019-07-03 09:44:24,892 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@949] - Client attempting to establish new session at /150.20.11.157:55746
  2019-07-03 09:44:24,908 [myid:3] - INFO  [CommitProcessor:3:ZooKeeperServer@694] - Established session 0x300393be5860001 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /150.20.11.157:55746
  2019-07-03 09:44:26,410 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@222] - Accepted socket connection from /150.20.11.157:55748
  2019-07-03 09:44:26,411 [myid:3] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@903] - Connection request from old client /150.20.11.157:55748; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
  2019-07-03 09:44:26,411 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@949] - Client attempting to establish new session at /150.20.11.157:55748
  2019-07-03 09:44:26,422 [myid:3] - INFO  [CommitProcessor:3:ZooKeeperServer@694] - Established session 0x300393be5860002 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /150.20.11.157:55748
  2019-07-03 09:45:41,553 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1056] - Closed socket connection for client /150.20.11.157:55746 which had sessionid 0x300393be5860001
  2019-07-03 09:45:41,567 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1056] - Closed socket connection for client /150.20.11.157:55744 which had sessionid 0x300393be5860000
  2019-07-03 09:45:41,597 [myid:3] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@376] - Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x300393be5860002, likely client has closed socket
  2019-07-03 09:45:41,597 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1056] - Closed socket connection for client /150.20.11.157:55748 which had sessionid 0x300393be5860002
  2019-07-03 09:46:20,896 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@222] - Accepted socket connection from /10.32.0.5:45998
  2019-07-03 09:46:20,901 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@949] - Client attempting to establish new session at /10.32.0.5:45998
  2019-07-03 09:46:20,916 [myid:3] - INFO  [CommitProcessor:3:ZooKeeperServer@694] - Established session 0x300393be5860003 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /10.32.0.5:45998
  2019-07-03 09:46:43,827 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@222] - Accepted socket connection from /150.20.11.157:55864
  2019-07-03 09:46:43,830 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@949] - Client attempting to establish new session at /150.20.11.157:55864
  2019-07-03 09:46:43,856 [myid:3] - INFO  [CommitProcessor:3:ZooKeeperServer@694] - Established session 0x300393be5860004 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /150.20.11.157:55864
  2019-07-03 09:46:44,336 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@222] - 
   Accepted socket connection from /150.20.11.157:55866
  2019-07-03 09:46:44,336 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@949] - Client attempting to establish new session at /150.20.11.157:55866
  2019-07-03 09:46:44,348 [myid:3] - INFO  [CommitProcessor:3:ZooKeeperServer@694] 
  - Established session 0x300393be5860005 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /150.20.11.157:55866
```

Would you please guide me how to use both Mesos slaves to run Flink platform?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide us with the logs from the two masters and slaves? This would help to understand what's going wrong with the leader election/retrieval.

Comment: Dear @Till Rohrmann, I have updated my question.